# Google Maps API zooming between Normal view & Street View?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

How do I transition to Street View from Normal View and vice-versa just by zooming in/out and not involving Pegman in the process?

So far, it seems the only way to transition between the two views is by placing the Pegman on the map - to enter Street View and clicking on the Cross button on the top-right - to exit Street View. I want to make the transition to mimic that of maps.google.com. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the example from the [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) for street view.

```
var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
var mapOptions = {
  center: fenway,
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var panoramaOptions = {
  position: fenway,
  pov: {
    heading: 34,
    pitch: 10
  }
};
var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
```

Then use an event handler for the zoom case.

Hope that helps :)